# How does d=${c//[^$b]} count how many times the letter $b is found in $c?

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "The program checks the number of indicated letters"
echo "Enter the file name and path"
read a
c=$(cat $a)
echo "
Enter which letter is to be found. for examle 'a' "
read b
d=${c//[^$b]}
echo "The number of occurrences of the character is: " ${#d}
```

I can't understand how this line works: `d=${c//[^$b]}`. The program works fine, I just don't understand how the expression `[^$b]` works. I have read that the expression `[^...]` matches any characters that are not in parentheses.

For example, if the user enters the character 'a', he will find the number of occurrences of this letter in the indicated file. Could someone help me and explain how this works because the definition `[^...]` says something completely different.

I found such a definition:
`"[^d]"` matches any character except those in the range b through d.
So if there are strings of sentences in the file that contain and shouldn't show them like this, unless I misunderstand something.

Comment: `${variable//match_pattern/replace_pattern}` falls under the heading of [parameter substituion](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html); in this case `[^$b]` says `everything that's not in variable 'b'`; `replace_pattern` is empty which means replace with nothing (ie, remove); net result ... `remove everything from variable 'c' that's not in variable 'b'` leaving you with just the parts of variable 'c' that match with what's in variable 'b'

Comment: `c=$(cat $a)` doesn't work in general.  `c=$(< "$a")` is reliable, and avoids running a new process.

Comment: `d=${c//[^$b]}` doesn't work if `$b` is backslash or `]`.  `d=${c//[^"$b"]}` always works.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds a few other issues with the code.

Answer (score 2):

`${s//x}` will *remove* all occurrences of `x` in the value of variable `s`. `[x]` will match any character in the list (the list contains a single character only, so only "x" will be matched). `[^x]` matches all characters *except* "x".

Therefore, `${a//[^x]}` will only leave the "x" characters in the value. `${#v}` gives the number of characters in the variable. Since only "x" characters are left in the variable, this gives you the number of those characters.

It's also possible to achieve the same by calling external programs and not only relying on bash variable expansion (IMO a bit more straightforward and expresses the intent more clearly):

```
echo "The number of occurrences of the character is: $(grep -oe "[$b]" "$a" | wc -l)"
```

Comment: @pjh thanks, I missed to provide the file name. It's fixed now

Comment: The `grep ... | wc -l` will usually work now.  It will break if the filename begins with `-` (dash/hyphen) or if the character to be counted is `.` (dot).

Comment: @pjh the same way the original `c=$(cat $a)` in the OP will break. But you are again correct, especially the behavior of matching characters is different. It should be `[$b]` at the very least. For filenames starting with hyphen: this is not something the script/binary must normally handle. Callers have to make sure to pass unambiguous options and filenames starting with `-` need to be passed as `./-`

Comment: The combination of `-F` and `"[$b]"` doesn't work.  `grep` is searching for a string with literal square brackets in it.  `$(grep -Fo -- "$b" <"$a" | wc -l)` works for all valid filenames (including ones starting with `-`) and for all characters except newline and ASCII NUL.